# DataReader.GetFieldType(30) returned null

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: DataReader.GetFieldType(30) returned null.

I tried all the fixes issued here on stackoverflow but it seems that it does not work on my part.

I'm working with an issue regarding Geography in SQLServer database. I don't have any issue with regards to other datatype but when a column have already a Geography. It produces an error.

I try to put Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll in the bin folder and reference it on the project. Same  error occur.

> {
>     "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>     "ExceptionMessage": "DataReader.GetFieldType(30) returned null.",
>     "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
>     "StackTrace": "   at System.Data.ProviderBase.SchemaMapping.SetupSchemaWithKeyInfo(MissingMappingAction mappingAction, MissingSchemaAction schemaAction, Boolean gettingData, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object chapterValue)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.SchemaMapping..ctor(DataAdapter adapter, DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Boolean keyInfo, SchemaType schemaType, String sourceTableName, Boolean gettingData, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillMappingInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 schemaCount, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillMapping(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 schemaCount, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.LoadAdapter.FillFromReader(DataTable[] dataTables, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)\r\n   at System.Data.DataTable.Load(IDataReader reader, LoadOption loadOption, FillErrorEventHandler errorHandler)\r\n   at System.Data.DataTable.Load(IDataReader reader)\r\n   at Arbiter.Core.BaseHelper.ExecuteReader()\r\n   at Arbiter.Helpers.SqlHelper.RetrieveT\r\n   at GjenesisServices.Models.DataAccessLayer`1.Retrieve(String command, Object[] parameters)

Comment: Adding the calling code will dramatically improve your chances of getting a helpful answer.

Comment: If you can share code of how are you querying the data and data type of the column set  in sql server that would help us understnding the questiom better.

Comment: I updated my question. I don't know which is triggering an error. Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you just add a try catch around the line where you extract the field type , set a breakpoint on the catch line and see what values you have in your data reader? Perhaps you can identify the row in the database which breaks the code and then implement the appropriate fix?

Comment: I'm having trouble with Geography column when I'm fetching the data. I'm not sure if how it can be solved. I try to put try catch but I need to solve the issue on how to get the data from Geography

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solve the issue.

The reference of Microsoft.SqlServer.Types should be on GAC

Plus, putting information in web.config

That fixed my problem